# Redis: Cannot perform full-text search operations

Tags: redis, next.js

I got error saying "ReplyError: Car:index: no such index". I am indexing by "description". As you can see on the terminal part contains all the needed info and I am not sure what is causing the problem. Help is welcome.

[image]
I've been trying to follow Fireship tutorial on Redis, copied his code https://fireship.io/lessons/redis-nextjs/

Comment: Have you called .createIndex() on the repository?

Comment: The instructions are a bit old and state that you need to do it once. The latest version of Redis OM doesn't require that. You can call .createIndex as often as you want and it will only recreate the index if the schema has changed.

Comment: You are right, the problem was in no calling createIndex API. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redis-om version 0.3.6, you can add following code in your API:

```
export async function createIndex() {
  await connect();
  const repository = client.fetchRepository(schema);
  await repository.createIndex();
}
```

And Also ensure you only create index once ONLY.

It will work after you created an index.

Answer (score 0):

As Guy Royse mentioned in the comments - The problem is solved by calling createIndex API.